# Google Canary - cannot uninstall

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-10

I'm using google canary and somehow, the canary window is appearing all black:

[image]

When I tried unistall the google canary, nothing happens. The icon appears like if the google canary is openned:

[image]

Anyone have any ideia what is happening?

Note: I'm using windows 10 Pro version 1703 OS Build 15063.726

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to launch it with compatibility mode set to Windows 7. It worked for me.

Source: https://www.ghacks.net/2017/12/12/how-to-fix-google-chrome-black-screen-issues/